# localhost / 127.0.0.1 suddenly(!) not working anymore (in general, not only for XAMPP)

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, hosts, hosts-file

I'm encountering a sudden problem with my localhost / 127.0.0.1 access.

Situation is as follows:
I'm using localhost / 127.0.0.1 for my developement enviroment server (XAMPP), so i can access the in-progress version of my project via browser. I also use it for for some other programs, not only for XAMPP.
Last night, when i stopped coding everything was still working fine, like everey day. But since today localhost is not accessible anymore - not via browser, not for other programs which used to use it.

- The hosts-file of Windows was NOT changed since when everything was functioning well
- The Problem occours not only when i try to access via browser / XAMPP. Seems to be a general localhost adressing problem
- Only action between working and not working state was turning off my computer last night and turning it on again today
- I've tried to re-install XAMPP and other relevant programs, still not working
- Same problem applies, when i try to access 127.0.0.1

I absolutely have no clue, what could'd be responsible for this. Has anybody a suggestion? Would be very happy about that!

PS: Sorry for my possibly bad English.

PPS: StackOverflow is such a cool website, it helped me like NO other in the last years with getting better in coding. Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sure port 80 is not occupied by other services for example like Skype

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer.

But yes, i'm sure.

No software was installed since when everything ran fine and no settings of any program where changed.

Additionally the proplem occours when i try to acces via port 80 AND when using port 443 (SSL / HTTPS).

Comment: Remember if Skype start before Xampp it might occupying port 80 even if everything was working and even if you have not changed anything

Comment: teamviewer also uses port 80, uninstalling teamviewer solved my problem

Comment: Thank you both too, but i have installed neither skype nor teamviewer :/

Comment: How did you solve it?